# SSH - Permission denied (publickey) issue from Mac OSX to CentOS server

Tags: ssh, centos8

(Most threads about this issue are either AWS or GitHub related. Mine is neither. It's a simple Digital Ocean CentOS 8 server.)

My old Macbook connects to my SSH server without any issues:, using

```
ssh -2 -p 5555 -i  /Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa  me@99.99.99.99
```

(Port number and IP changed for privacy, of course.)

I bought a new Macbook Pro, and have set up the `ssh-keygen` stuff as usual, then manually moved the `id_rsa.pub` to the server's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. On the server, I did this adding to the authorized keys file using nano while logged in as the root user. So this below is what the `.ssh` dir looks like on the server, when logged in as the root user:

```
990971649 -rw-------. 1 root root 2722 Jul  7 07:52 authorized_keys
990971651 -rw-------. 1 root root 3389 Jan 10  2021 id_rsa
990971652 -rw-------. 1 root root  747 Jan 10  2021 id_rsa.pub
```

But despite adding the id_rsa.pub stuff into the authorized_keys on the server, I get this error:

```
me@99.99.99.99: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Most threads on this issue have been 'solved' by adding some parameter, but my `ssh_config` settings on the server seem to be fine...and this works from my old Macbook! Below are the server settings--

```
Protocol 2
Port 5555

LoginGraceTime 60
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 3
MaxSessions  6
AllowUsers root 
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PasswordAuthentication  no
PermitRootLogin         yes
X11Forwarding           no 
MaxAuthTries            6 
IgnoreRhosts            yes
AllowTcpForwarding      no
AllowAgentForwarding    no
Compression             no 
TCPKeepAlive            no 
UseDNS                  no 
HostbasedAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication    yes

AuthenticationMethods   publickey
```

What else could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you share your sshd_config from the server?

Comment: Can you check the auth.log on your server with : grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log

Comment: I am on CentOS. There's no file like that. There however is `/var/log/secure` and that shows these errors: https://pastebin.com/bZMh0mRt

Comment: Can you try what i wrote in the update step by step. create a new user, deactivate everything i wrote and try to login only with username and password and no port select try with the standard 22. if this works change the port to your needs. than create a new key and upload with ssh-copy-key. try to login with the key now (-i), if this works edit your sshd_config to your needs, step by step(don't forget to restart the sshd server every time you doing changes. thats how i would doing find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

To address the issue of OpenSSH 9.0p1 disabling RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm by default, you can follow these steps to modify the ssh_config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Add the following lines to the bottom of ssh_config:

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

> **sshd_config is the configuration file for the OpenSSH server. ssh_config is the configuration file for the OpenSSH client.
> Make sure not to get them mixed up**

You need to edit the server config file not the client config file (**ssh_config**)

Add or edit this in your **sshd_config**

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

IF you don't wanna login with passwords only keys edit this too:

But first try to login with the key than edit this to no if the server is not on the same location!

```
PasswordAuthentication  no
```

And don't login as root security!

```
PermitRootLogin         no
```

You can use **ssh-copy-id** to copy the key to the server

```
ssh-copy-id  -i ~/.ssh/[KEY] -p [PORT] [user]@[IP]
```

**UPDATE:**

Uncomment all this lines in your sshd_config an try to login with a allowed/existing user only with the password to find out if there are other errors:

DON'T FORGET TO RESTART THE SSH SERVER EVERY TIME YOU CHANGE SOMETHING IN THE SSH SERVER FILES:

```
#LoginGraceTime 60
#ClientAliveInterval 120
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#MaxSessions  6
#AllowUsers root 
#PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PasswordAuthentication  yes
#PermitRootLogin         yes
#X11Forwarding           no 
#MaxAuthTries            6 
#IgnoreRhosts            yes
#AllowTcpForwarding      no
#AllowAgentForwarding    no
#Compression             no 
#TCPKeepAlive            no 
#UseDNS                  no 
#HostbasedAuthentication no
#PubkeyAuthentication    yes
#AuthenticationMethods   publickey
```

Comment: Yes that code I shared above is in fact on the server. These settings make no difference. Still get the error. (And no, ssh-copy-id won't work -- same error)

Comment: You edit the sshd_config or ssh_config?

Comment: What is the error message of ssh-copy-id?

Comment: The error message of ssh-copy-id is exactly the same. The ssh_config of the server is what I've included in my question: this is the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the CentOS server.

Comment: If you try to login only with a password not with the key you get the same error message? Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: There is no password. I just use the key on the old Macbook.

Comment: There must be a password for the user "me" on the server try to login with this user(change his password on the server if you lost) because with your config file it looks like that you can login with a key or with a password from the user with out a key.

Comment: try to uncomment this too : #HostbasedAuthentication no

Comment: There's no user called "me". It was me masking an old user ID for public posting here. I've removed that line. The updated `sshd_config` file is in my question now -- no impact though, same error.